# Nested list into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am extracting text part by part from an unspecified number of PDFs and store the extraction in a nested list (A parent contains the extracted sections of a PDF). For later operations I need a dataframe with a column for the sections (one section per row) and a second column with the reference from which document (index of the first list) the part comes.

After the initial creation of the list (loop which creates a temporary list which is later attached to a "master list") I convert the list into a Pandas.Series which is then transferred into a Pandas dataframe. The indexes are later added to the dataframe via another loop.

My surely very unnecessarily complicated solution is not very robust, because the index does not always arrive in the dataframe. Do you have an idea how I can solve this problem in a more sophisticated manner?

```
def load_pdfs(*files):
    final_list = []
    for file in files:
        # load pdf and extract paragraphs from it.
        pdf_bytes = textract.process(file, encoding='ascii')
        # bytes to string decoding
        pdf_string = pdf_bytes.decode("utf-8")
        # Create a list which contains each line as an item
        RegEx_list = re.split('\n',pdf_string)
        # join items with no blank item (--> paragraph separator) inbetween
        temp_list = [x for x in ' '.join('---' if not e else e for e in 
        RegEx_list).split('---') if x]
        final_list.append(temp_list)

    global df_pdf
    df_pdf = pd.Series([item for row in final_list for item in row], name="paragraph")
    print(df_pdf)
    df_pdf = df_pdf.to_frame()
    df_pdf["doc"] = ""

    row_start = 0
    doc = 0
    for lst in final_list:
        length = len(lst)
        target_row = row_start + length
        df_pdf.doc.loc[row_start:target_row] = doc
        row_start =+ length
        doc =+ 1

    return final_list
'''
```

Comment: Hello. In order to help us help you better, please edit your answer to include what your current output looks like along with the output you expect should look like.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the lack of information. Sometimes you're so deep into a topic that you don't immediately notice the lack of detail, I'll work on that :) The user in the other comment could solve my problem.

Comment: That's good to hear. Please mark the answer below as the solution then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you want is to make

```py
final_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]
```

to become like

```
  paragraph doc
0         a   0
1         b   0
2         c   0
3         d   1
4         e   1
```

then you can use [pd.Series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

```py
df = pd.Series(final_list, name='paragraph').explode().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'doc'})
print(df)
```

will return

```
   doc paragraph
0    0         a
1    0         b
2    0         c
3    1         d
4    1         e
```

or if you're using lower version of pandas, you can simply add the row index with `enumerate`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([(item,row_ix) for row_ix, row in enumerate(final_list) for item in row], columns=['paragraph', 'doc'])
print(df)
```

```
  paragraph  doc
0         a    0
1         b    0
2         c    0
3         d    1
4         e    1
```

Comment: That was exactly what i was searching for. And sorry for the missing information, I hadn't noticed it when I was writing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']]

# Concatenate elements into a single array
all_elements = np.concatenate([sublist for sublist in lst])
"""print(all_elements)
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'E' 'F' 'G' 'H']
"""

# Generate keys using descriptive variables
 # Array of keys for each sublist
sublist_keys = np.arange(len(lst))
"""print(sublist_keys)
[0 1 2] 
"""
 # Lengths of each sublist
sublist_lengths = np.array([len(sublist) for sublist in lst]) 
"""
print(sublist_lengths)
[2 3 4]
"""
repeated_keys = np.repeat(sublist_keys, sublist_lengths) + 1  # Repeat keys with offsets
"""
print(repeated_keys)
[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]
"""
# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'lst': all_elements, 'key': repeated_keys})
"""print(df)
  lst  key
0   A    1
1   B    1
2   C    2
3   D    2
4   E    2
5   E    3
6   F    3
7   G    3
8   H    3"""
```